# Regex How to find exact word between " and /

Tags: regex, editpad

So I build the regex below that does it job well.

```
"item_name\/": \/"[a-zA-Z1-9 ]{1,}\/
```

This will successfully find all text below:

```
"item_name/": /"Legendary Frost Armor/
"item_name/": /"Branch/
"item_name/": /"Tier 5 Legendary Stick/
"item_name/": /"Potato/
"item_name/": /"Seaweed/
"item_name/": /"Mage Legendary Rune/
```

However, I only interested in selecting those that contain Legendary so it should end up like this:

```
"item_name/": /"Legendary Frost Armor/
"item_name/": /"Tier 5 Legendary Stick/
"item_name/": /"Mage Legendary Rune/
```

Do note that they are not separated by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"item_name\/": \/"[a-zA-Z1-9 ]*Legendary[a-zA-Z1-9 ]*\/
```